# Setting a css property using a normal variable for knockout js

Tags: javascript, html, css, knockout.js

I want to set the css property using if condition using a normal variable other than observables. Like:

**a.html** file:

```
<span class="label" data-bind="text: isApproved, css: sampleglobalvar == true ? 'label-success' : 'label-important'"></span>
```

**a.js** file:

Edit:

```
define('durandal/app'],function(app) {
   var a = function() {

    sampleglobalvar = 'true'
    };
}
```

I am getting an error such as 'sampleglobalvar' doesnt exist in viewmodel .
I know that a observable has to be used , but I have other problems with observable where switching between 'true' and 'false'
for observables was creating problems:

Like if I use:

```
sampleglobalvar = ko.observable("");
```

setting :

```
if(//condition)
{

sampleglobalvar(true);
}
else
{
sampleglobalvar(false);
}
```

was not clearing the observable properly , due to which I am getting different results.

***To summarize is it possible to use a normal javascript variable to use it in css data-bind property?***

Comment: You put the 'sampleglobalvalue' in an annonymus function, making it a NON global....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's perfectly possible. For true global (i.e. stuff on `window`) you need to scope the variable in your databinding though.

Example:

```js
function RootViewModel() {  
  // Plain property on the "global" (i.e. Root) view model:
  this.plainProp = true;
  
  // True "global" variable:
  window.myGlobal = true;
}

ko.applyBindings(new RootViewModel());
```

```css
.error { background: red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<p data-bind="css: plainProp === true ? 'error' : 'plain'">Root plain prop</p>
<p data-bind="css: window.myGlobal === true ? 'error' : 'plain'">Global plain prop</p>
```

You've included function scopes and a module loader (requirejs?) in the mix in your question, but as long as you get the scopings right for that exact scenario it should work analogous to my example. If you have a problem with *that* particular bit, I suggest asking another question, including a Minimal Repro (i.e. more (and syntactically valid) code than what the question currently has).